# How to test simple backend program on localhost in android?

Tags: php, android

I made very simple backend program (it only sends simple request) but, it occurs error.

Here is my front-side code.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/test.php";
RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
         JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("login.java response", response.toString());

                    int l=  response.length();
                    try {
                        if(l>1){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.getString("valid"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        else{               

                        }   
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, 

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("error", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    // hide the progress dialog
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server Error, try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        // Adding request to request queue
             mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
        }
    });
}
```

}

And back-end side code.

echo json_encode("return");

It's path:"c:\wamp\www\test.php".
If I run this program, it shows "Server Error, try again".

I can get "return" on web browser, so I think there is a problem about url in android program.
I turned off windows firewall, but it didn't work also.

Is there anyone who has rich experience with this problem and can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You should provide the Android app with actual IP address of the machine you have your server running on. You can learn your IP by typing in console `ipconfig` (for Windows), `ifconfig` for UNIX systems. 
It most likely be `192.168.1.xxx` or `172.16.xxx.xxx`.

Comment: I tested it with actual ip adress before, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the url to your IP-address, instead of

```
"http://localhost:8080/test.php";
```

Use your local ip address (for example) :

```
"http://192.168.0.1:8080/test.php";
```

Comment: I tested it with my ip address, before. But it didn't work. I set my ip address to "192.168.1.32".